# What button terminology should I use for filtering?

Tags: gui-design, buttons, search, terminology, filter

I feel that having 'Filter' and 'Filter' is repetitive. Any suggestions on making this more intuitive for users?

[image: Filter bar]

Comment: Use **apply** text instead of filter as said by @anna prenzel.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, the user will understand that the section is a filter section when it has the action button labelled 'Filter'. Having a label Filter  as well as a filter action button is more of redundancy I could say.

If you wish to retain the label and **if** the page is **not** content intensive site, then you can load the contents dynamically when the user applies the filter. You wouldn't require an action button here.

**If your page is content intensive, the above mentioned technique will not be advisable since it will consume more page load time which will affect the experience of the user adversely**

Answer (score 2):

I often see the caption "Apply" on the button. That means "the filters are applied".

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Material design - Text for buttons and related elements](https://material.io/guidelines/style/writing.html?hl=es-mx#writing-language).

I would either avoid the use of the button if you can update the results smoothly as the user selects from the dropdown (as Google does);

or **remove the label and just show the Filter button**.

Comment: I agree with both recommendations here.

Removing the filter label and replacing it with a filter icon could work well.

If the dataset is not very comprehensive and additional requests wouldn't impact performance negatively, removing the button and updating the view with each selection would work well.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Filter" is ok for the title, but for the button is better to use "Search", "Find" or "Explore".